# SoapUI / ReadyAPI Groovy script to get value of xml node

Tags: xml, groovy, soapui

I'm using a Groovy script in SoapUI / ReadyAPI to grab the value of an XML node response, however I've come across an issue. Below, you will find what the output of the value is:

```
[<a:SessionStatus xmlns:a="url">OK</a:SessionStatus>]
```

The issue is I just want the output of the value to be "OK". Below, you fill find my XML and Groovy script.

XML:

```
<"CreateSessionResult xmlns:a="url">
    <"a:SessionStatus>OK</a:SessionStatus">
```

Note: Ignore the " " marks in the XML CreateSessionResult, as I had to put those to get the XML tags to display

Groovy Script:

```
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context);
def holder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder("CreateSession#Response");

holder.namespaces["a"] = "url";
def nodes = holder.getDomNodes("//a:SessionStatus");

def list = [];

for(node in nodes)
{
   java.io.StringWriter writer = new java.io.StringWriter();
   com.eviware.soapui.support.xml.XmlUtils.serialize(node, writer);
   list.add(writer.toString());
}

log.info(list);
```

Comment: So I don't know anything about SOAP UI, but have you tried simply using a Groovy XmlSlurper or XmlParser?  Seems like they might be easier to use than the SOAP UI junk.

Comment: Is it possible to show the  valid xml? Is `SessionStatus` repetitive element?